# update value to dynamic associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have dynamic array created from query result.

Now I want to update one key in array. My array format is

```
  [94] => Array
        (
            [property] => 00251
            [bulilding] => 03
            [unit] => 000311

        )

    [95] => Array
        (
            [property] => 00251
            [bulilding] => 01
            [unit] => 000309

        )
```

There is loop  of this array running and I have query on basis of values of this array and if I am getting result in query then I have to insert that value to array.

So it should be something like

```
[94] => Array
        (
            [property] => 00251
            [bulilding] => 03
            [unit] => 000311
            [newval] => 000311   // This will be inserted

        )

    [95] => Array
        (
            [property] => 00251
            [bulilding] => 01
            [unit] => 000309
           [newval] => 4545// This will be inserted

        )
```

Any idea how can I make this possible ? Help Please

Comment: you question is not clear @Lerry. Please format the code also explain a bit more like what is your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$new = array_merge( $your_array, array( "Stack" => "Overflow" ) );
```

Update

```
$array  =array(
        0 => array(
                'property' => 00251,                
                'bulilding' => 03,
                'unit' => 000311,                   
            ),
        1 => array(
                'property' => 00251,                
                'bulilding' => 03,
                'unit' => 000311,                   
            ),
    );
    $new = array();
    foreach($array as $arr){
     $new []= array_merge( $arr, array( "Stack" => "Overflow" ) );
    }
    print_r($new)
```

Comment: Thanks @Shravan,I have done this but this is showing like 


[95] => Array
        (
            [property] => 00251
            [bulilding] => 01
         [unit] => 000309
        )

    [newval] => 280


I want newval to be in array but it showing outside.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
<?php

    $array  =array(
            0 => array(
                    'property' => 00251,                
                    'bulilding' => 03,
                    'unit' => 000311,                   
                ),
            1 => array(
                    'property' => 00251,                
                    'bulilding' => 03,
                    'unit' => 000311,                   
                ),
        );

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);

        $i=1;
        foreach($array as $key => $val) {        
            if(isset($val) && !empty($val)){
                $array[$key]['newval'] = "new_value_".$i; // please explain how you are fetching newval for more detailed solution      
                $i++;           
            }

        }

        print_r($array);
    ?>
```

Comment: Its giving me  [newval] => new_value_ at last of array completion which I need in each array

Comment: Isn't this the output that you want ?